# extracting regions from a range file in a formatted output perl

Tags: perl

I have a input and list file like this:

input.txt file:

```
>gi|NP_415931.4
MTEQQKLTFTALQQRLDSLMLRDRLRFSRRLHGVKKVKNPDAQQAIFQEMAKEIDQAAGKVLLREAARPEITYPD
>gi|NP_418770.2
MMNKSNFEFLKGVNDFTYAIACAAENNYPDDPNTTLIKMRMFGEATAKHLGLL
>gi|YP_026226.4
MRKFTLNIFTLSLGLAVMPMVEAAPTAQQQLLEQVRLGEATHREDLVQQSLYRLELIDPNNPDVVAARFRSLLRQGDIDGAQKQ
```

list.txt file:

```
NP_415931.4: 1-5, 6-8
YP_026226.4: 3-7, 9-9, 10, 12-15
```

Now, for this time, I want a csv formatted output.csv (with certain added header) as (for the above inputs):

```
ID,Regions,Length,Sequences
NP_415931.4,1-5,5,MTEQQ
,6-8,3,KLT
YP_026226.4,3-7,5,KFTLN
,9-9,1,F
,10,1,T
,12-15,4,SLGL
```

that is, it first match the list file headers with those of input files and the matched once's sequences are taken and then it gives the output arranging in the above format.

the excel view of the output.csv would be:

[image]

How can I generate the above output.csv file from those inputs?

Thanks

Comment: Can you divide your problem in smaller problems? It's kind of hard to process all the information all at once. So if your problem is that you want a text to csv formatter, then you should have just said, "I have this input and I want this output. I have tryed this and that."

Comment: csv formatted output.txt is a misnomer, my apologies.. it should be output.csv,, n actually i have the one input and one list file as mentioned above. from it, i want the .csv formatted output as given

Comment: In this case a simple google search for `text to csv perl` would have lead you to the right answer

Comment: actually the problem is quite different and tricky for me.. I have just edit my post and mentioned only the exact problem (excluding the script which i used for a rather simpler scenario) as u suggested.. may be this time it will be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach. To summarize: We have a master database file `input.txt` with all defined sequences. Our job is to extract certain information from this database and write it to a CSV file. The information about what to extract is given in file `list.txt`.

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_fn = 'input.txt';
open ( my $fh1, '<', $input_fn ) or die "Could not open file '$input_fn': $!";
my %seqs;
while( my $line = <$fh1> ) {
    my ($id ) = $line =~ /gi\|(.*)$/;
    chomp( my $seq = <$fh1> );
    $seqs{$id} = $seq;
}
close $fh1;
say join ',', qw(ID Regions Length Sequences);

my $list_fn = 'list.txt';
open ( my $fh2, '<', $list_fn ) or die "Could not open file '$list_fn': $!";
while( my $line = <$fh2> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ( $id, @regions ) = split /[:,]\s?/, $line;
    for my $i (0..$#regions) {
        my $region = $regions[$i];
        my $start = my $end = $region;
        if ( $region =~ /(\d+)-(\d+)/ ) {
            $start = $1;
            $end = $2;
        }
        my $name = ($i == 0) ? $id : "";
        my $seq = substr( $seqs{$id}, $start - 1, $end - $start + 1);
        say join ',', $name, $region, length( $seq ), $seq;
    }
}
close $fh2;
```

**Output**:

```
ID,Regions,Length,Sequences
NP_415931.4,1-5,5,MTEQQ
,6-8,3,KLT
YP_026226.4,3-7,5,KFTLN
,9-9,1,F
,10,1,T
,12-15,4,SLGL
```

Comment: it is working fine.. but in the "Region" column instead of showing "1-5", it shows "01-May".. may be it interferes with the MS Excel date formatting.. could it be changed to something like ".."?

Comment: @J.Carter Great. Unfortunately I am not familiar with Excel, but to change the dash into double dots, try for example `$region =~ s/-/../`

Comment: thank you very much, i'm trying it now.. it seems that only substituting  - to .. in last line wont help , $region should print it in itself

Comment: You are welcome. Try inserting the substitution on `$region` on a line below `my $seq = `

Comment: you are absolutely right sir.. thank you once again.